# How to implement the "Pin it" function from pinterest

Tags: javascript, pinterest

I'm trying to make a new pin it button just like Pinterest has, I've see the content at that bookmark:

```
javascript:void(
  (function(){
    var e=document.createElement('script');
    e.setAttribute('type','text/javascript');
    e.setAttribute('charset','UTF-8');
    e.setAttribute('src','http://assets.pinterest.com/js/pinmarklet.js?r='+Math.random()*99999999);
    document.body.appendChild(e)
  })()
);
```

I'm new to javascript, so I am not sure how to start to do a new one. I have even no idea where should I start my coding. Is the backend for this Pin it button limited? Can anyone introduce how does this Pin it button works? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically what that code does is injects a `<script>` tag into the page. The actual "pin it" code is located in the `pinmarklet.js` file.

To make your own feature like this, you can just reuse the code and replace the source with your own JavaScript file.

Side-note: the `void(...)` part is redundant because the function doesn't return anything anyway.

Comment: I see, so if I have my own pinmarklet.js file, then ask the link to call my js will have the same purpose? Let's say like storing the picture into my own database.

Answer (score 2):

The code you posted simply injects a JavaScript file into the page's DOM which will cause it to get interpreted by the JavaScript engine. What you should be more interested in is the code in this file which implements the "Pin It" functionality:
http://assets.pinterest.com/js/pinmarklet.js

But since that is minified and somewhat obfuscated and probably proprietary, I would suggest what you want first is an easy to follow tutorial on how to create a Bookmarklet:
http://betterexplained.com/articles/how-to-make-a-bookmarklet-for-your-web-application/

Then, you need to think about how you will code your own web application to respond to asynchronous requests to "Pin" or save something. The following two simple but useful JavaScript variables could come in handy if you're just going for a simple "link-submission" type of functionality:

- **document.location.href** -- to get the page's *URL*
- **document.title** -- to get the contents of the page's *TITLE* tags

To compress your code into a single-line as is required by bookmarklets, you could use this tool:
http://subsimple.com/bookmarklets/jsbuilder.htm

Comment: This makes me feel a little bit like jquery. (Like the document and the element stuff). Are they related?

Comment: Yes, actually, while you don't need jQuery to develop a Bookmarklet, it can definitely simplify the process (particularly any DOM manipulation or AJAX request stuff to pass data between the Bookmarklet and your web app). Here's a similar Bookmarklet tutorial which focuses on using jQuery:
http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/05/23/make-your-own-bookmarklets-with-jquery/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add it to a button here is how:

html:

```
<button id="pintrest">Pin It</button>
```

And you script:

```
var btn = document.getElementById("pintrest");
btn.onclick = function () {
    var e = document.createElement('script');
    e.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
    e.setAttribute('charset', 'UTF-8');
    e.setAttribute('src', 'http://assets.pinterest.com/js/pinmarklet.js?r=' + Math.random() * 99999999);
    document.body.appendChild(e);
};
```

Now when you click on the button it should run the pintrest code

Comment: So if I want to set my own customized javascript code, the button should be mostly the same? I only have to modify the js code?

Comment: actually you customize only the button, and the js code stays the same

Comment: Really? What if I want to capture other content on the webpage? Let's say get the title instead of the picture?

Comment: you can add more js to the function, but you dont need to modify the pintrest script beyond what i added to my answer

Comment: So, if I have my own js file, I should replace the link to the pinterest js file to my own one? I don't quite understand the `var e = document.createElement('script');` part though...

Comment: what the script does is that it adds a new script tag to the document, that's it. You don't need to modify that. if you have you can add this code to your script, without modifying it